# Show that if $n$ is not prime then $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is not a field

Tags: finite-groups, finite-fields

I read book of Dummit and Foot Abstract algebra. I need some help with the following question.

> Show that if $n$ is not prime then  $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is not a field

I know definitions of field and  group $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}.$ I have no idea how to start it.

Comment: if $n$ is not prime there $n=ab$ with $1<a,b<n$...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

If $n$ is not prime, use the fact that $n=n_1n_2$, where $1<n_1,n_2<n$ to find divisors of $0$ in $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 0):

Field definition states closure under addition and multiplication.

If $\mathbb Z\setminus{n \mathbb Z}$ is a field than:

For $n_1,n_2 \in \mathbb Z \setminus{n \mathbb Z}$ than field definition requires that $n_1 * n_2 \in \mathbb Z \setminus{n \mathbb Z}$

Write $n$ as $n_1 * n_2$ while $n_1,n_2 > 1$ (therefore $n$ is not prime), assume negative that $\mathbb Z\setminus{n \mathbb Z}$ is a field and show the contradiction.

Comment: But for prime $n=5=2+3,$   $\mathbb{Z} /n \mathbb{Z}$ is a field

Comment: Write the other way, 8 and 9 are not primes so they are part of the field, so 8 + 9 = 17 should also be part of the field, but 17 is prime.

Comment: I think You are wrong.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics)#Definition_and_illustration Look for closure under addition.

Comment: @Liza I am sorry I misread the question, I fixed my answer. Use closure under multiplication.